# "Script Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN"

Tags: ssis

We have a scheduled job which executes a SSIS package daily and it has been working fine. But recently for one customer, it fails with below error and again works fine without any fix for the same data source file. The same issue is happening for different data source files and it is not consistent.

Below are the log details when the package fails. We have `DelayValidation` set to True for the data flow task. Can someone help me on how to fix this issue?

Details from log file:

```
04/20/2018 2:00:08 PM: About to execute the package
04/20/2018 2:00:08 PM: Execute result: Failure
04/20/2018 2:00:08 PM: Executing the package resulted in 4 error(s)
04/20/2018 2:00:08 PM: Error: The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully.
04/20/2018 2:00:08 PM: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError
04/20/2018 2:00:08 PM: Error: "Script Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

04/20/2018 2:00:08 PM: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError
04/20/2018 2:00:08 PM: Error: One or more component failed validation.

04/20/2018 2:00:08 PM: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError
04/20/2018 2:00:08 PM: Error: There were errors during task validation.

04/20/2018 2:00:08 PM: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError
```

Code from where error thrown:

private void RecompileScriptSource()
        {
            IDTSComponentMetaData100 srcComp = m_Pipeline.ComponentMetaDataCollection[BASE_SCRIPT_SOURCE_COMPONENT];

```
        // Get design time instance of script source
        CManagedComponentWrapper scriptSourceWrapper = srcComp.Instantiate();

        // Get script host & save
        try
        {
            ScriptComponentHost host = (scriptSourceWrapper as IDTSManagedComponent100).InnerObject as ScriptComponentHost;
            if (host == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to get access to the host object for the script component.");
            }

            if (!host.LoadScriptFromComponent()) // This returns false
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to load script information from component.");
            }
            VSTAComponentScriptingEngine engine = host.CurrentScriptingEngine;

            if (engine.VstaHelper == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Vsta 3.0 is not installed properly");
            }

            if (!engine.LoadProjectFromStorage()) // This returns false
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to load project files from storage object");
            }

            if (!host.SaveScriptProject())
            {
                log("Failed to save script project");
            }
            else
            {
                log("Saved script project");
            }

            engine.DisposeVstaHelper();
        }
        finally
        {
            log("Finished saving (or compiling or whatever");
        }

        // Validate script source
        DTSValidationStatus stat = scriptSourceWrapper.Validate();
        switch (stat)
        {
            case DTSValidationStatus.VS_ISBROKEN:
                log("Script source validation result says BROKEN");
                break;
            case DTSValidationStatus.VS_ISCORRUPT:
                log("Script source validation result says CORRUPT");
                break;
            case DTSValidationStatus.VS_ISVALID:
                log("Script source validation result says VALID");
                break;
            case DTSValidationStatus.VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA:
                log("Script source validation result says NEED NEW METADATA");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code doesn't rot. What does the code do (aka post it) and what is different between the executions?

Comment: Below is the code from where error is thrown and there is no difference between executions:

Comment: @Venkatesh I don't see the code you say you added.   Don't try to put code in a comment.   Click the "edit" link below your question and add it to the original question.

Comment: @TabAlleman - I have updated the code and error thrown when executing below code DTSValidationStatus stat = scriptSourceWrapper.Validate();

Comment: Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Any solution to this problem ? now it's happening in 2019 ssis